# How can I search for existing nodes with "Text format" = "undefined"?

Tags: nodes, migrations, input-formats, 10

I've upgraded to Drupal 10 from an earlier release, which used the PHP module (not yet available for Drupal 10). Therefore, I had to uninstall the PHP module before upgrading, leaving the "Text format" undefined for any node originally using that input filter.

How can I search for existing nodes with "Text format" = "undefined", so that I can fine-tune those?

(I have direct access to the database, and I can perform SQL queries.)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you asking how to find those nodes using a query you run on, for example, phpMyAdmin?

Comment: As a side note, there will never be a Drupal 10 release for the *PHP* module. It is better to not depend on that module and find alternatives.

Comment: I can actually run queries directly within mysql. And, yes, I am in fact looking for alternatives to the PHP module, although I wonder how I can embed the output of a php+mysql query (on a separate database than the one Drupal relies on) inside a Drupal node.

Comment: There is already a patch for Drupal 10 FYI @apaderno : https://www.drupal.org/project/php/issues/3363035

Comment: @Webdrips Do you think that a project that marked all its releases as not secure will commit that patch? I would not have hopes for that.